# How do I troubleshoot an unstable Internet connection in Precise after trying to install package with synaptic?

Tags: 12.04, networking

I was trying to install packages with synaptic. The internet connection cut off, and now is extremely unstable. It is not a problem with the internet connection itself because now I am on Windows.

How do I troubleshoot this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu internet connection is very unstable, all of a sudden](http://askubuntu.com/questions/243424/ubuntu-internet-connection-is-very-unstable-all-of-a-sudden)

Comment: Although OP seems to have used another name to post.

Comment: That was my post when I was panicked and back on Windows, before I came to my senses and signed in. Maybe the other post should be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

How to troubleshoot networking problems?  Google yields what looks like a good resource:

- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=25557

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Whilst your comment is theoretically correct, I don't consider it sensible to post a general network troubleshooting guide here.

Comment: It's true it shouldn't be posted verbatim: copyright problems, plus, answers should be customized to fit the question. But posting a general network troubleshooting guide here *is what you did*. You just posted it as a link that can change without warning. It seems to me this has the disadvantages of a general guide, and only some of the advantages. In particular, if a general guide would be considered off-topic on Ask Ubuntu, so would this. (But I don't think it would--so long as it's geared toward Ubuntu users.) Anyway, it's your choice, though someone may choose to expand this themselves.